# How to install Tktable for Python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tktable

I have downloaded the archive from here:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/?source=navbar

But how to install it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing myself and found `pip install tkintertable`. Not sure if this is the same as tktable though